# In Visual Studio when debugging C# code, can I export a List or a Dictionary in xml,csv or text format easily?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual Studio when debugging C# code, can I export a `Dictionary<string,string>` in xml,csv or text format easily?

I would like to export a `Dictionary<string,string>` in excel and see 2 columns of strings.

Debugging such dict in VS is cumbersome.

If there s any add on that simplifies visualization that s ok too.

Comment: `string.Join("\n", dictionary)` or [Enhancing Debugging with the Debugger Display Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can [add a watch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx) to your Dictionary (or List), then under the *Watch Window* you can then expand the entire dictionary (or List), right click, **select-all**, **copy**

[image: Export]

Then in Excel you can paste the data and it should auto-format:

[image: Excel]

You could also just paste this data directly into another text-editor (or just view the data directly in the watch window too).

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 15):

You could use a simple snippet like this:

```
var output = dict.Select(kv => string.Format("{0},{1}", kv.Key, kv.Value));
File.WriteAllLines("output.csv", output);
```

As noted in the comments, if your dictionary keys or values contain any commas or newlines, you'll need something slightly more complex to generate valid a CSV file.

Comment: It's important to note that this naive approach can result in ambiguous output if the inputs contain commas or linebreaks.

Comment: You could use `File.WriteAllLines`, so you don't need to concatenate the individual lines into a huge string.

Comment: True, and true. I started writing this answer with code to quote the fields and escape quotes inside values etc, but it started getting beyond "simple snippet" territory.

Comment: @CodesInChaos in that case, a proper CSV (and probably XML) is impossible by definition, due to various reasons, including charset limitations and no de facto CSV standard covering all CSV consumers. IMO there's no portable and standard way to escape arbitrary 8-bit characters in CSV (you can aim for it partially, but some characters [low ASCII values, corresponding to control chars especially] are bound to cause trouble; doing it properly in XML is also quite tricky). As such, I consider this answer valid, given the limitations implied by OP himself.

Comment: @vaxquis I consider this a valid answer as well, it's just important to understand its limitations/pitfalls.

Answer (score 9):

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. For debugging purposes, you can convert dictionary to multiline string using LINQ query:

```
string description =
    string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
        dict.Select(tuple => $"{tuple.Key} => {tuple.Value}").ToArray());
```

Maybe this will be enough for debugging.

Answer (score 5):

## Use The Immediate Window

Don't underestimate the power of the immediate window for this kind of thing.

My advice is to add an extension method to Dictionary which creates your csv file, then, in the Immediate window, you can call it whenever and wherever you need.

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static string ToCsvFormat<TK,TV>(this IDictionary<TK,TV> dict)
    {
        var sw = new StringWriter();
        foreach(var kv in dict)
        {
            sw.WriteLine($"{kv.Key}, {kv.Value}");
        }
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

Here's a C# fiddle of the extension method in action:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/f8xQjs

And to use it in the immediate window:

```
foo.ToCsvFormat(),nq
```

the ",nq" option causes it to properly handle multi-lines.  Then you can copy/paste from the immediate window and you're good to go.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to remove the '$' in writeline.  Also if your TV Value is an array you can loop through with `foreach (var item in kv.Value as Array)`

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2022 now has the feature built in as per [MSDN View Data in IEnumerable Visualizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/view-data-in-ienumerable-visualizer?view=vs-2022).