# Visual Studio / Reflection / Serialization: Can I export values from a debug session to use them for unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, serialization, reflection, reflector

I had to write many dozens of lines of code (see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RiVx2E) to generate a few lines of sample data.

In this specific case I could manually export the output variable (see the whole code on Fiddler) in this way:

```
new List { 
 { IDMacroTab = 1, IDTab = 1, IDSIot = 2 }
 { IDMacroTab = 1, IDTab = 2, IDSIot 1}
 { IDMacroTab = 1, IDTab = 2, IDSIot = 2}
 { IDMacroTab = 1, IDTab = 2, IDSIot = 3}
 { IDMacroTab = 2, IDTab = 1, IDSIot = 1}
 { IDMacroTab = 2, IDTab = 1, IDSIot = 2 }
 { IDMacroTab = 2, IDTab = 2, IDSIot = 1}
 { IDMacroTab = 2, IDTab = 2, IDSIot = 2}
 { IDMacroTab = 2, IDTab = 2, IDSIot = 3}
 { IDMacroTab = 3, IDTab = 1, IDSIot = 1}
 { IDMacroTab = 3, IDTab = 1, IDSIot = 2}
 { IDMacroTab = 3, IDTab = 2, IDSIot = 1}
 { IDMacroTab = 3, IDTab = 2, IDSIot = 2}
 { IDMacroTab = 3, IDTab = 2, IDSIot = 3}};
```

Is there any workaround that allows to serialize an object to the c# lines of code required to populate it?

Comment: Nothing built in, and make sure you don't step on a slippery slope here. Generating large amounts of data for unit-test purposes might sound good in theory but in practice it can lead to brittle tests, just make sure you don't end up replicating the "database problem" for unit-tests, just through code.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: thanks. Usually in my real cases they are not so big amount of data.. often they are complex objects.

Comment: You could write the data to a file using JSON. You can inspect a variable in the Command Window. You can [convert it to JSON](https://martynsmutterings.wordpress.com/2018/02/05/getting-your-object-in-json-in-the-immediate-window-in-visual-studio/) with `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myVariable);`. Add a `File.WriteAllText` in front to write the text out to a file. Not the most intuitive way but it's one option

Comment: Check [LINQBridgeVs](https://github.com/codingadventures/LINQBridgeVs) too. It's a Debugger visualizer that sends data to Linqpad for scripting and testing. You could use it as is, or modify the code to create your own visualizer that saves data to files

Comment: Thanks! guys. I've also found an old plugin.. I will try: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OmarElabd.ObjectExporter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### First solution (partial)

I've found this question which can be pretty useful but just for some kind of object (i.e. lists)

[In Visual Studio when debugging C# code, can I export a List or a Dictionary in xml,csv or text format easily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132735/in-visual-studio-when-debugging-c-sharp-code-can-i-export-a-list-or-a-dictionar/41132925#41132925)

[image]

[image]

### Second solution

And also this plugin ObjectExporter (last update 2017; checked at 2018)

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OmarElabd.ObjectExporter

[image]

Comment: Last updated 06/03/2017, 07:22:35. As by now, not supported in VS2022. Thanks and goodbye.

Answer (score 2):

**Thrid Solution: ObjectDumper.NET**

I might have another solution for you. I was using OmarElabd/ObjectExporter in previous projects with good results but there were problems with some kind of types (e.g. serializations of DateTime didn't work properly at the time). Performance was key too: Some generated objects had a size of 50k lines of code (yeh, don't mention this is too big for a single test data class, I know, but...).

After all, I started writing my own **ObjectDumper** which you can find published as a **NuGet package** here. The source code is hosted on github, so feel free to contribute.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObjectDumper.NET/

The idea of ObjectDumper.NET is that you can dump basically *any* C# object back to C# initializer code. Compared to ObjectExporter (which is a Visual Studio plug-in), ObjectDumper is installed as NuGet Package. This allows ObjectDumper to be used at *runtime* - not only at the time of code creation.

**Example Usage:**

```
[Fact]
public void SerializeObjectsToInitializerCode()
{
    // Create C# object
    var testObjects = new List<TestObject>
    {
        new TestObject {IDMacroTab = 1, IDTab = 1, IDSIot = 2},
        new TestObject {IDMacroTab = 1, IDTab = 2, IDSIot = 1},
        new TestObject {IDMacroTab = 1, IDTab = 2, IDSIot = 2}
    };

    // Pass it to ObjectDumper, choose DumpStyle.CSharp to generate C# initializer code
    var dump = ObjectDumper.Dump(testObjects, DumpStyle.CSharp);

    // Print to console, write to file, etc...
    _testOutputHelper.WriteLine(dump);
}
```

[image]

Comment: ObjectExporter supposedly works during debugging which unlike what you said, it works during runtime. How is one going to get the objects with data if not during runtime?

Comment: Ok you're right. But there is a "during runtime while debugging" and "during runtime without debugging" which makes the difference. ObjectExporter is a Visual Studio plugin. ObjectDumper is a nuget package which can be installed to any project and run in debug and release builds. Take which ever fits your needs ;-)

Comment: Btw. I'm not sure if there is someone going to create a VS2022 version of ObjectExporter.