# Excel: convert JSON-like data {column1name = value, column2name = value} to a normal Excel table with column header

Tags: c#, excel, debugging

Thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132735/in-visual-studio-when-debugging-c-sharp-code-can-i-export-a-list-or-a-dictionar/41132925#41132925) I've found out that it's possible to export this kind of data from the Visual Studio Debugger.

The data come in the following format:

```
{ IDSport = 1, IDEvent = 1, TournamentName = "Primera Division", EventDate = {08/19/2018 02:00:00}}
{ IDSport = 1, IDEvent = 1, TournamentName = "Primera Division", EventDate = {08/19/2018 02:00:00}}
```

[image]

And that's what I would like to get. I can use SQL, Regex, LINQPad. But I couldn't find an easy and immediate solution.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I've found a solution by using a text editor

```
Replace [ → {
Replace ] → }
Change only the first { with [
Change only the first } with ]
Use a website to convert JSON to Excel (i.e https://codebeautify.org/json-to-excel-converter)
```